# Dependence or independence to php frameworks

Tags: php, frameworks

I'm studying php programming and I'm pretty convinced I know base rules that permit me to move on pretty building good web application.It could be weird but from the beginning I started to build web application using frameworks.I know how php works (session,cookies,ecc...) but if you say me to create a web application without a framework I could have some problems because I don't have a mind schema to follow instead with framework I'm fell more comfortable because I follow simple pattern like MVC and I have everything clear in my mind. what I'm asking now is this situation is really convenient for a web programmer? I web programmer especially in the last times, have to be independent or dependent from frameworks?

Comment: Probably more appropriate to ask on programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: no need to reinvent the wheel(with bugs), just study up a little on patterns, so you know what you are actually using: registry, mvc, composition, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perfectly possible to build a PHP application without any framework, but it is more time consuming.

If you want perfect control over every part of your code, don't use a framework. This option also lets you optimize your code fully.

However, using an existing framework may well be easier and less time consuming, in some cases at the expense of performance. I would say that the performance loss is negligible in most cases, but it really depends on the application.